# loop inside spark RDD filter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter, rdd

I am new to Spark and am trying to code in scala. I have an RDD which consists of data in the form :

```
1: 2 3 5
2: 5 6 7 
3: 1 8 9
4: 1 2 4
```

and another list in the form [1,4,8,9]

I need to filter the RDD such that it takes those lines in which either the value before ':' is present in the list or if any of the values after ':' are present in the list.

I have written the following code:

```
val links = linksFile.filter(t => {
                        val l = t.split(": ")
                        root.contains(l(0).toInt) ||
                        for(x<-l(0).split(" ")){
                            root.contains(x.toInt)
                        }
                    })
```

linksFile is the RDD and root is the list.

But this doesn't work. any suggestions??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close: the for-loop just doesn't actually use the value computed inside it. You should use the `exists` method instead. Also I think you want `l(1)`, not `l(0)` for the second check:

```
val links = linksFile.filter(t => {
                        val l = t.split(": ")
                        root.contains(l(0).toInt) ||
                        l(1).split(" ").exists { x =>
                            root.contains(x.toInt)
                        }
                    })
```

Answer (score 0):

For-comprehension without a `yield` doesn't ... well ... yield :)
But you don't really need for-comprehension (or any "loop" for that matter) here.

Something like this:

```
linksFile.map(
   _.split(": ").map(_.toInt)
 ).filter(_.exits(list.toSet))
  .map(_.mkString)
```

should do it.